# How to select include directory search order in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have two files with the same name **proj-conf.h**. I want the one that resides in my project to be included. The file is in **${ProjDirPath}/src/library/proj-conf.h**.

In my project **properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->[Includes]** I have this include directory added: **${ProjDirPath}/src** which is on the top of the list. I guess that this is the first place the compiler searches for include files, since it is on the top of the list?

So in my main application **${ProjDirPath}/src/main.c** I have this directive: `#include "library/proj-conf.h"`.

Why am I getting the error:

> library/proj-conf.h: No such file or directory

?

**EDIT:::**

[image]

Comment: are you sure that `-I ${ProjDirPath}/src` is passed at compiler command?

Comment: lol actually the consol shows this `-I"C:/Users/rmrd001/git/electricity-meter/electricity-meter-controller.src"` While I am expecting this: `-I"C:/Users/rmrd001/git/electricity-meter/electricity-meter-controller/src"`.

Comment: What is your type of project? Eg. with autotool you must specify CFLAGS into makefile.am. Setting eclipse project property only help IDE indexer.

Comment: It is a Silicon Labs eclipse based IDE. They have their own type named : Silicon Labs MCU Project

Comment: Is there a makefile? Out of curiosity: this [mrd](http://www.mrd-institute.com/)?

Comment: Yes there are multiple make files

Comment: You could try to see if modification into eclipse project options causes accordingly a modification into makefile. If not, I guess you must modify them by hand.

Comment: Yes they change accordingly. The problem is that I was looking at the parent directory makefile instead of the makefile of the folder itself. Respectively I was neglecting the fact that each folder into the project has its own settings for the include search directories. This is wath I have been missing. The eclipse is a new animal to me. May be I should have started with that statement. The problem is solved. Thank you @LPs !